# What is $\#Hom(\mathbb Z_{2p^a}, D_{p^a})$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Please tell me if I am making any mistake on the following.

We are willing to find out the number of group homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z_{2p^a}$ to $D_{p^a}$ where $p$ is odd prime, $a\in \mathbb N$ and $D_n$ is dihedral group of order $2n$.

We know that $\#Hom(C_n, G)=\#\{x\in G: x^n=e\}$ when $C_n$ is cyclic group of order $n$. In other words, we just have to search the number of elements of each order $d$ whenever $d|n$.

Suppose we denote the number of elements of order $d$ in a group $G$ by $\eta_d(G)$. Then the given problem is equivalent to find 
$$h:=\sum_{d|2p^a}\eta_d(D_{p^a}).$$

Now we have $\eta_{2p^i}(D_{p^a})=0~\forall~i\in \{1, 2, \cdots, a\}$ because there is no element of order $2p, 2p^2, 2p^3, \cdots, 2p^a$. Hence 
\begin{align*}
h=~&\eta_{1}(D_{p^a})+\eta_{2}(D_{p^a})+\eta_{p}(D_{p^a})+\eta_{p^2}(D_{p^a})+\cdots+\eta_{p^a}(D_{p^a})\\
=~&1+p^a+\varphi(p)+\varphi(p^2)+\cdots+\varphi(p^a)\\
=~&p^a+\sum\limits_{d|p^a}\varphi(d)\\
=~&p^a+p^a\\
=~&2p^a
\end{align*}

In other words, the number of group homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_{2p^a}$ to $D_{p^a}$ is $2p^a$.

Did I make any mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if you did any mistake, but you can easily see that
$$\# \operatorname{Hom}(\Bbb{Z}_{2p^a}, D_{p^a}) = \# \{ x \in D_{p^a} : x^{2p^a} = 1\} = \# D_{p^a} = 2p^a$$

The second equality follows from the fact that in a finite group $G$ of order $n$ you have $$\forall x \in G \ \ \ x^n=1$$

Comment: Ohh thats so nice. I didn't think in this way. Thank you.

Comment: Between, suppose the question was how many homomorphisms are there from $\mathbb Z_m$ to $D_n$. Should we declare the result as $\sum\limits_{d|(m, 2n)}\eta_d(D_n)$ ? Because using the fact you provided above would say that any element satisfying $x^m=e$ also satisfy $|x|$ divides $2n$ ?

Comment: My argument works in the case that $2n$ divides $m$. Otherwise your argument is needed (which is correct).